# triple summation and loop and r

Tags: r, function, loops, nested

R users 
I am going to write codes for the expression in the form like 
`sum(l(from 1 to n))sum(i(from 1 to m))sum(t(from 1 to m)[phil(i)*phil(j)*I(X(l)<min(y(i),y(t)-z(i)z(t)]`

I think I should use a loop, so have define the function like

```
fun1<-function(phil,x,y,z){s1<-phil(j)*phil(r)*(x(l)<min(y(i),y(t))-z(i)*z(t))}
s1=0
for (t in 1:m ) 
s1<-phil1(i)*phil1(t)*(x(l)<min(y(i),y(t))-z(i)*z(t))
for (i in 1:m)
s2=sum(s1)
for (l in 1:n)
s3=sum(s2) #not sure what commands I can put here
```

can someone give me some ideas for writing up this code
Thank you very much!!!

Comment: First advice: use *blocks* of code '{ ... }' to put the content of your loops.

Comment: Additional advice:  Read `?"["`

Comment: sapply, sapply, sapply

Comment: Thank 4 any advice, this summation mixes with sub-functions phil(j)/phil(i) which is a function with variable z, hence, I feel so confused when writing up codes, actually, have no idea where I should start.  Anyway, Thanks your help!!!!